# S2S VPN on AWS EC2 - routing issue for VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, iptables, vpn, routing, terraform

I'm trying to prepare VPN setup from scratch. I used Terraform + AWS + Strongswan. Basic diagram is attached here:
[AWS diagram, S2S VPN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPKQJ.png)

So I have VPC_left:     `172.32.0.0/16` with subnet_left: `172.32.10.0/24` with 2 ec2, one is going to establish VPN (`172.32.10.10`), the other one can be treated like application node (`172.32.10.11`). Both nodes have public IP assigned.

There is VPC_right: `172.33.0.0/16` with subnet_right: `172.33.20.0/24` with another 2 ec2s, and similarly one is going to establish VPN (`172.33.20.20`), the other one can be treated like application node (`172.33.20.21`). Both nodes have public IP assigned.

Starting from my problem - I have successfully created S2S VPN between those 2 subnets, and such flow is working fine (both ping + telnet on 22 or any other port):

```
172.32.10.10 -> 172.33.20.20
172.32.10.10 -> 172.33.20.21
172.33.20.20 -> 172.32.10.10
172.33.20.20 -> 172.32.10.11
```

But I have problem with VMs that didn't create tunnel, such connection is not working:

```
172.32.10.11 -> 172.33.20.20
172.32.10.11 -> 172.33.20.21
172.33.20.21 -> 172.32.10.10
172.33.20.21 -> 172.32.10.11
```

There are no errors in StrongSwan logs, and tunnels seems to work. I must have done something wrong with routing.

Terraform code for aws_route_tables:

```
resource "aws_route_table" "public_left" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.dev_network_left.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"

    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.main_left.id
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "public_left"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table" "public_right" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.dev_network_right.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"

    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.main_right.id
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "public_right"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table" "private1_left" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.dev_network_left.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"

    gateway_id = aws_nat_gateway.gw1_left.id
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "private1_left"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table" "private1_right" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.dev_network_right.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"

    gateway_id = aws_nat_gateway.gw1_right.id
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "private1_right"
  }
}
```

And this it also output from ip route from left nodes:

```
root@ip-172-32-10-10:~# ip r
default via 172.32.10.1 dev ens5 proto dhcp src 172.32.10.10 metric 100 
172.32.0.2 via 172.32.10.1 dev ens5 proto dhcp src 172.32.10.10 metric 100 
172.32.10.0/24 dev ens5 proto kernel scope link src 172.32.10.10 metric 100 
172.32.10.1 dev ens5 proto dhcp scope link src 172.32.10.10 metric 100

root@ip-172-32-10-11:~# ip r
default via 172.32.10.1 dev ens5 proto dhcp src 172.32.10.11 metric 100 
172.32.0.2 via 172.32.10.1 dev ens5 proto dhcp src 172.32.10.11 metric 100 
172.32.10.0/24 dev ens5 proto kernel scope link src 172.32.10.11 metric 100 
172.32.10.1 dev ens5 proto dhcp scope link src 172.32.10.11 metric 100
```

What seems wrong to me is traceroute output from 172.32.10.11:

```
root@ip-172-32-10-10:~# traceroute -p 22 172.33.20.20
traceroute to 172.33.20.20 (172.33.20.20), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  172.33.20.20 (172.33.20.20)  1.261 ms  1.198 ms  1.239 ms

root@ip-172-32-10-11:~# traceroute -p 22 172.33.20.20
traceroute to 172.33.20.20 (172.33.20.20), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  240.0.12.14 (240.0.12.14)  0.261 ms 240.0.12.15 (240.0.12.15)  0.177 ms 240.0.12.13 (240.0.12.13)  0.208 ms
 3  241.0.1.12 (241.0.1.12)  0.344 ms 241.0.1.5 (241.0.1.5)  0.179 ms 241.0.1.15 (241.0.1.15)  0.182 ms
 4  242.0.117.105 (242.0.117.105)  1.057 ms 240.0.12.18 (240.0.12.18)  0.212 ms 240.0.12.26 (240.0.12.26)  0.181 ms
 5  * 242.0.117.225 (242.0.117.225)  0.737 ms 242.0.117.121 (242.0.117.121)  3.990 ms
 6  52.93.142.115 (52.93.142.115)  3.081 ms 52.93.142.117 (52.93.142.117)  3.024 ms 52.93.145.196 (52.93.145.196)  4.465 ms
...
a lot of other public IP addresses
...
```

Maybe iptables will be usefull in this case too for both 172.32.10.10 and 172.32.10.11 (no entries for .11):

```
root@ip-172-32-10-10:~# iptables-save
Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Thu Dec 14 19:55:32 2023
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.33.20.0/24 -o ens5 -m policy --dir out --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.33.20.0/24 -o ens5 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
Completed on Thu Dec 14 19:55:32 2023

root@ip-172-32-10-11:~# iptables-save
root@ip-172-32-10-11:~#
```

Do you know what is my problem here? If there is anything more that might help, please let me know, I will send all necessary information.

Comment: What do you mean with `But I have problem with VMs that didn't create tunnel`. Keep in mind that a s2s vpn is a vpn between networks, so on the VM'S you need to make sure that traffic is send over the VPN. Usually you need to set the vpn gateway as a gateway using a static route i think. According to the AWS docs `If you attach a VPC to your transit gateway and you want to enable resources in the VPC to reach your customer gateway, you must add a route to your subnet route table to point to the transit gateway.`

Comment: See also here https://vkontech.com/aws-site-to-site-vpn-with-strongswan/#VPN_Configuration_on_EC2-B

Answer (score 1):

your applicative ec2 is not aware that a VPN exist on the strongswan ec2 to reach the other side.

you must create a static route.

- either in the AWS subnet route table that points to the ENI of the
  strongswan EC2
- or directly in the OS of applicative EC2 that points to the IP of the strongswan ec2

AWS have managed solutions to interconnect networks, like VPC peering or transit gateways. I think it is better than the manual way, but maybe you have a good reason

Comment: Thank you, it helped! I tried with `ip route` on the ec2 and it didn't help, probably because AWS is overriding it?  

But when I added it via AWS (VPN -> Route tables -> Routes -> Edit routes -> right subnet 172.33.20.0/24 with network interface of Strongswan ec2 - 172.32.20.20, it started to work immediately.
I was wrongly trying to set NAT Gateway and other targets, but it doesn't make sense apperently.  

And I'm using such config as we have also some setup on-premise and on less popular cloud solutions, that's why I don't want to use too much features from AWS to have same config.

Comment: perfect, happy ending !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Strongswan, but if you're using an EC2 instance effectively as a router, you may need to disable the source/destination check from Terraform or the EC2 Console. This check prevents then instance from forwarding traffic if it's not the source or destination. This may be blocking traffic from transiting the tunnel.

In terraform you add `source_dest_check = false` to the instance arguments, in the console you go `Instance Details` -> `Actions` -> `Networking` -> `Change source/destination check` and turn **on** '*Stop*' (there's a double negative there, so double check the wording!).

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it seems that there is no difference in behavior with `source_dest_check = false` or `true`. I did change routing that @exeral suggested, and it helped. But still, it's good to be aware of such settings!

Comment: My fault, it happened that both of the changes were necessary, so you and @exeral helped me a lot! Thanks one more time.